# How can I download specific rows using SQL in pgadmin

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin

I want to export csv file, but there needs to be specific rows for example from 20000 to 40000. I want these rows only to be exported.

Is there any SQL queries to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a view which generates the rows you want:

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_view AS (
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
        FROM yourTable
    ) t
    WHERE rn >= 20000 AND rn < 40000
)
```

Then, just do a `SELECT *` from this view when using your tool.